# Join and select multiple column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

I'm trying to select multiple columns after doing a join. I couldn't find a way to do so using ActiveRecord without writing SQL between quotation marks in the query (Thing I'd like to avoid)

Exploring Arel, I've found I could select multiple columns using "project", however I'm not quite sure if I should use Arel directly or if there was a way to achieve the same with AR.

These is the code in Arel:

```
l = Location.arel_table
r = Region.arel_table

postcode_name_with_region_code = l.where(l[:id].eq(location_id)).join(r).on(l[:region_id].eq(r[:id])).project(l[:postcode_name], r[:code])
```

After running this query I'd like to return something along the lines of:
(*Pseudo-code*)

```
"#{:postcode_name}, #{:code}"
```

1. Is there a way to achieve the same query using AR?
2. If I stick to Arel, how can I get the values out of the SelectManager class the above query returns.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Using AR, without writing any SQL and assuming your models and associations are:

models/region.rb

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end
```

model/location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

You can certainly do:

```
postcode_name_with_region_code = Location.where(:id=>location_id).includes(:region).collect{|l| "#{l.postcode_name}, #{l.region.code}"}
```

This will do the query and then use Ruby to format your result (note that it will return an array since I'm assuming there could be multiple records returned). If you only want one item of the array, you can use the array.first method to reference it.

You could also eager load the association and build your string from the result:

```
 my_loc = Location.find(location_id, :include=>:region)

 postcode_name_with_region_code = "#{my_loc.postcode_name}, #{my_loc.region.code}"
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for you answer. 

That brings another question, in terms of performance, wouldn't be more effective to do a joins as opposed to includes? It might not be significant performance hit with this query but I saw it queries the DB twice when using includes.

Comment: The joins won't really buy you anything in this case. If you want to try, replace .includes(...) with .joins("JOIN locations.region_id ON regions.id").  The second query is a result of the collect statement querying for the region's code.  I've added a solution that leverages the AR eager loading of the association if you want to give that a try too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.  

After a bit of a playing with AR this was the query I started to use:  

`Location.joins(:region).where(:id =>location_id).select('locations.postcode_name, regions.code').map{|l| "#{l.postcode_name}, #{l.code}"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
predicate = Location.where(:id=>location_id).includes(:region)
predicate.ast.cores.first.projections.clear
predicate.project(Location.arel_table[:postcode_name], Region.arel_table[:code])
```